# "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have got this error while working with laravel. I am trying to save a book data and save its owner user with user_id. Sorry about question format.

```
public function store(InfoValid $request)
{
    $request->validated();
    $user = Auth::user()->books()->create($request->except('_token'));
    //dd($user ->user_id);
    Book::create($request->except('_token'));
    redirect("/books");
}
}
```

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `books` (`name`, `page`, `ISBN`, `price`, `published_at`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values)) ◀"

in my User class i have:

```
public function books(){
    return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
}
```

and in my Book class:

```
protected $fillable = [
    "name" , "page" , "ISBN" , "price" , "published_at"
];

public function user()
{
return $this ->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and in my books table:

```
$table->unsignedInteger("user_id");

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

When i dd() the user_id(i have commented that) it gives me the user_id but i don't know why i'm facing this error

Comment: Are you specifying the value for `user_id` while you insert (answer is no)? Does the field `user_id` exist in your table (answer is yes)? What should the value be for the `user_id` when you *don't specify it in the insert*? A default value. That wasn't specified while creating the table. So, why do you get that error then? I gave you all the clues, and the error message tells you why also.

Comment: What the default value should be? i gave defined it nullable but whenever i saved a book actually 2 books(one for null and another fo user_id) were saved.

Comment: Why do you have this line `Book::create($request->except('_token'));`? You should probably remove it. You've already saved it with `books()->create(...)`.

Comment: Oh! thank you. i removed it and it works.  I'm new to laravel and php. i saw in a video for another project and didnt notice that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Auth::user()->books()->create($request->except('_token'));
```

Will set the `user_id` in the `Book` entity automatically.

But here

```
Book::create($request->except('_token'));
```

the `user_id` will not be set. So laravel will try to insert the book without `user_id` (which is required), and MySQL will complain. But you also don't need that second line, since the book is already saved with the first one.